# Why I have error with validation - validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have this validates

```
   validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true
```

I dont have a field in my database called terms_of_service, In my view I have

```
    <%=f.check_box :terms_of_service %>
```

If I select the checkbox everything works, but when I dont select the checkbox I tried to create the record I have this error

```
    undefined method `counts' for #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f83f01b6a18>
```

The error is in this view

```
   <% if @model.errors.any? %>
     <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@model.errors.counts, "error") %> prohibited this   model from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
       <% @model.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
       <% end %>
      </ul>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

Any idea, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in this line:

```
<h2><%= pluralize(@model.errors.counts, "error") %>
```

You probably want `#count` not `#counts`

ie:

```
<h2><%= pluralize(@model.errors.count, "error") %>
```

Also, for next time, please include the *entire* error trace in your post.

More info available at the [documentation page for ActiveModel::Errors](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-count)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the `terms` box isn't checked, the validation fails and your error is rendered, but the error message has an error - `counts` should be `count`

Try adding a custom message to your validator:

```
validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: { true, 
                             message: "You must accept the terms of service to continue"}
```